# How to add a id or class to a HTML dropdown in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

How to add a id or class to a HTML dropdown  in yii2? I found this code on stackoverflow but i am unable to add a class/id to this dropdown list.

```
 Html::dropDownList( 'ddlname',
    'selected option',  
    ['a'=>'A', 'b'=>'B'] 
  )
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `I found this code on stackoverflow but i am` to lazy to use google. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList%28%29-detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way :

```
<?php 
    echo  Html::dropDownList( 'ddlname',
      'selected option',  
       ['a'=>'A', 'b'=>'B'], 
       ['class' => 'your_class', 'id' => 'your_id']
    )
?>
```